# The official embedded example didnt seems to work.org.neo4j.dbms.api.DatabaseNotFoundException

Tags: neo4j

I created a local dbms with neo4j desktop app with name aa,and a password,test and followed the example in https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/java-embedded/hello-world/, but it throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.dbms.api.DatabaseNotFoundException: AA
        at org.neo4j.dbms.database.DatabaseManagementServiceImpl.lambda$database$0(DatabaseManagementServiceImpl.java:76)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
        at org.neo4j.dbms.database.DatabaseManagementServiceImpl.database(DatabaseManagementServiceImpl.java:76)
```

So the question is what do we as user need to do to fix it then, or is there assumption?

---

- do I happen to need a neo4j desktop running the server?
- do i just need to setup the database with the desktop app?
- or is there a way to use the java api to create and access the infos then do the stuff?
- is this referred to as *operate embedded clusters*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you "embed" neo4j, the neo4j DBMS runs *inside* of your Java application.

The [hello world example](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/java-embedded/hello-world/) includes this line:

```
graphDb = managementService.database( DEFAULT_DATABASE_NAME );
```

The value of `org.neo4j.configuration.GraphDatabaseSettings.DEFAULT_DATABASE_NAME` is `neo4j`, not `AA`.

But even if the default name were `AA`, it would nevertheless refer to the DB that is *inside* of your application, not one outside.

Also, the embedded examples are only valid for the Community Edition. If you want to run embedded Enterprise Edition, you need to ask neo4j professional services for support.

Now, if all you want to do is to use Java to access an *unembedded* neo4j DB, you should use the [neo4j Java driver](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/current/languages-guides/java/java-intro/).

Comment: changing to "neo4j" worked.However I am curious in what is the reasoning for it. -does the string refers to one of the built in database as stated in https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/introduction/cypher_neo4j/ ?

Comment: Yes, it is the name of the builtin default DB.

Comment: I updated my answer to indicate that `DEFAULT_DATABASE_NAME` is actually a constant that you can use (instead of hardcoding 'neo4j').